# how can I solve r57shell_php_php warnings?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, security, error-handling

My host provider has sent to me an email which it says my application have some malwares and I should fix them .that email also contains the following list:

> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/usr/ local/apache.ea3/conf/modsec2. user.conf.rpmsave
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/servina_db/qmx72_ rsfirewall_signatures.MYI
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/servina_db/qmx72_ rsfirewall_signatures.MYD
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/carmane0_arman/ar_ redirection_404.MYD
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/carmane0_arman/ar_ redirection_404.MYI
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/ofoghdat_rez/iev7c_ rsfirewall_signatures.MYD
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/ofoghdat_rez/iev7c_ rsfirewall_signatures.MYI
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/jammashi_db/i6bm7_ rsfirewall_signatures.ibd
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/iimenlo2_saeed/ln8qc_ rsfirewall_signatures.MYD
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/iimenlo2_saeed/ln8qc_ rsfirewall_signatures.MYI
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/packagin_db3/l2p08_ rsfirewall_signatures.MYI
>
> {YARA}eval_post : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/packagin_db3/l2p08_ rsfirewall_logs.MYD
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/packagin_db3/l2p08_ rsfirewall_signatures.MYD
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/ofoghdat_db/rnghu_ rsfirewall_signatures.ibd
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/ofoghdat_ge/iev7c_ rsfirewall_signatures.MYD
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/ofoghdat_ge/iev7c_ rsfirewall_signatures.MYI
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/iturkey1_testsh/vnjca_ rsfirewall_patterns.MYD
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/iturkey1_testsh/vnjca_ rsfirewall_patterns.MYI
>
> {YARA}r57shell_php_php : /home/virtfs/username/var/lib/ mysql/lemoda_lmag/flsdc_ rsfirewall_signatures.ibd

I used php for my application and it contains some simple `SELECT` and `UPDATE`s.
I don't have any idea what these are and how can I fix them.
any help will be appreciated.
thanks .

Comment: It is malware. It is not easy to remove malware from php scripts. You can have a look, if there is a root kit installed somewhere. Have a look which files on your server have been changed recently. Look at the content in these files. Clean up. The cleanest way would be to delete all the files on your server and replace them with a backup you hopefully made in the past. Check your script for security vulnerability.

Comment: You can see that most of the files that are detected are the virus signature itself (*.ibd. *.MYI). Meaning that your antivirus detects your antivirus signature as a virus. This is bad signature.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a false positive.

`{YARA}r57shell_php_php` is the pattern matching file that Maldet uses to guess at malware when it doesn't know for sure.

Tell your hosting provider that it's likely a false positive once you've scanned the files visually.